# US visitor visa for a self-employed applicant (India)

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I am an Indian passport holder. The main source of my income is from our own apple crops, as we have an apple orchard here. I don't have any other employment but I do have a good balance (500,000) in my Indian bank account. How would this be viewed by the US Embassy when it considers my visa application?

Comment: Why is nobody answering my question here? I appolize, if this is an off-topic question or maybe i asked it on a wrong site.

Comment: You asked it 2 hours ago, on a Saturday evening (in Europe at least). Please be patient, as people aren't sitting waiting to answer questions. You may need to wait until Monday or Tuesday to get answers.

Comment: Give it some time; this is an question and answer site, with the participation of people from around the world who share their knowledge and experience. Someone will come along, see your question and respond, perhaps ask you to clarify (as I did in my edit).

Comment: Please see Gayot Fow's excellent guide https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/60813 . Basically, you need to have regular income and expenditure that makes it clear that you have a reliable source of income. Even if you work for yourself, you should have salary and tax payments that are transparent. The authorities want to ensure that you have a legal business and the source of the funds is clear.

Comment: They're looking for people who are committing crimes, smuggling, planning to seek employment or overstay.   Owning a farm at home quells any concern of "overstay", but they will want to know that you're not seeking employment (including work-trade) off season, and that you will be able to support yourself in expensive Ameica without working, and that your travel plan makes sense for tourism or other allowed purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From anecdotal experience (helped a few friends and heard a lot of feedback), US doesn't seem to care as much about your income as UK. Your travel history is way more important to get a visa. Some of people I know well, who are just backpacking the world and have no serious income, got the US visas easily. And some other people with good income and property ownership were refused visas because they didn't have any significant prior travel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I dont have a traval history as im visiting a foregin country for the first time. Would it cause problems in my visa?

Comment: Yes, it may cause problems. The Embassy might wonder why the US is your first travel destination when there are so many countries nearby which are closer and cheaper. This is something you would need to address proactively, as otherwise they would suspect your intentions are not tourism.